# Optimizing the for loop so that all elements from a table are scraped correctly using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping all values from [here](https://www.spacresearch.com/symbol?s=live-deal&sector=&geography=)
While I get the desired output, a caveat is the when I inspect the elements in the table  tags..on one day I get 145 rows, on another day I get 143 rows, and on another day I get it around 140 rows...Simply put, I want to optimize the logic so that whatever is the last element record in the  tag for eg: 145,150,132... it runs fine.

Here's a piece of code for the same:

```
table_row = []
for i in range(1, 142):
    temp = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="companies-table-deal-announced"]/tbody/tr[' + str(i) + ']').find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    table_row.append(list(map(lambda x: x.text, temp)))
print(table_row)
df = pd.DataFrame(table_row,
                          columns=['SPAC', 'Target', 'Ticker', 'Announced', 'Deadline', 'TEV ($M)', 'TEV/IPO', 'Sector',
                                   'Geography', 'Premium', 'Common', 'Warrant'])
```

A way in which I can think is to use a len() in the for loop and make it work, Is there another way to do it optimally? Please let me know, Thanks!

Comment: You can use if driver.findElements(By.id("...")).isEmpty() == True: break in an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.spacresearch.com/symbol?s=live-deal&sector=&geography=")
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='companies-table-deal-announced']//tbody//tr")
for i,tab in zip(range(1,len(table)+1),table):
    datalist=[]
    data = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    for d in data:
        datalist.append(d.get_attribute("innerText"))
    print("{}: {}".format(i,datalist))
```

Output:

```
1: ['Ace Global', 'DDC Enterprise', 'ACBA', '8/25/2021', '4/8/2022', '300']
2: ['NextGen Acquisition II', 'Virgin Orbit', 'NGCA', '8/23/2021', '3/25/2023', '3,218']
3: ['Aldel Financial', 'Hagerty', 'ADF', '8/18/2021', '4/13/2023', '3,134']
...
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I am actually saving all these information in a list of list which is then getting saved to pandas dataframe.. It has all the values from all 11 columns.

Comment: @technophile_3 - Updated that code. I am not sure about 11 columns.  I could only see 7.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks alot, it requires a login after which you can get data for all 11 columns.. I'll check this code. Thanks

Comment: your code works thanks alot!! However I am facing issues while inserting the values in my dataframe.. I get this error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (12, 1), indices imply (12, 12)

Comment: @technophile_3 - No idea about dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
It can parse page and find elements by it's id and iterate over them.
Like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
soup = BeautifulSoup([page], 'html.parser')
content = soup.find(id='companies-table-deal-announced')
for element in content:
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, Since the rest of the logic is in selenium I am looking specifically for seleniium